# Show divs based on text search

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a text input search that is supposed to filter divs based on the title of the div. Here is the code that is not working:

```
$('.contact-name').each(function(){
  var txt = $('#search-criteria').val();
  $('this').find(txt).show()      
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
To clarify the variable txt is what the user has typed in the input field. An example would be if txt was Cha I would want this row to show:

```
<div class="contact-name"><h3><a href="##">Charles Smith</a></h3></div>
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

try this

```
var txt = $('#search-criteria').val();
$('.contact-name:contains("'+txt+'")').show();
```

**[documentation for :contains() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)**

**fiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/WBvTj/2/**

**UPDATE CASE INSENSITIVE:**

```
var txt = $('#search-criteria').val();
$('.contact-name').each(function(){
   if($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(txt.toUpperCase()) != -1){
       $(this).show();
   }
});
```

**fiddle Example : http://jsfiddle.net/WBvTj/4/**

Comment: See the my additional explanation above. I am look to the evaluate the text inside the div.

Comment: That is working mostly, is there a way to make that case insensitive?

Comment: And to not search hidden rows.

Comment: updated the code for case insensitive... what do you mean by hidden field ??? is it a input hidden type or div with visibility hidden ???

Comment: Thanks i have used this , [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16987520/2218697) is similar, for **more example and effects** , just google `jquery live text search` hope helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

The following should be case-insensitive, and match only on text in first a href in the div:

```
var pattern = "/" + $('#search-criteria').val() + "/i";
$('.contact-name').filter(function() {
    return $(this 'a:first-child').html().match(pattern).length > 0;
}).show();
```

filter gives you a list of elements that return true from that function in it to apply show() to.
The return in the filter function can be read as: "for the first anchor element in this element, take the contents, match it against the pattern, and if the resulting array contains 1 or more results, return true".

The "i" on the end of the pattern is what gets you case-insensitive matching.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily jQuery has a **[Contains](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/)** selector:

```
$('.contact-name').each(function(){
  var txt = $('#search-criteria').val();
  $(this).find('div:contains("'+txt+'")').show()      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `find` method takes a JQuery selector as parameter. I doubt your `search_criteria` text input will contain that. Assuming it will contain some substring of the DIV's title, then try this:

```
var txt = $('#search-criteria').val();    
$('.contact-name').each(function(i, e){
  if($(e).attr("title").indexOf(txt)>=0) $(e).show();
});
```