# Javascript search form on div contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a 'form search' function script that I am trying to apply to items within a container. I have found this from a [tutorial online](http://jsfiddle.net/lmac1/x6kv91qk/) that someone used to search members of teaching staff. only I am looking to apply this to my div classes:

```
$('.form-search').on('submit',function(){return false;});
$('.form-search .btn').on('click', function(e){
    var query = $.trim($(this).prevAll('.search-query').val()).toLowerCase();
    $('div.dress-container .bold').each(function(){
         var $this = $(this);
         if($this.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(query) === -1)
             $this.closest('div.dress-container').fadeOut();
        else $this.closest('div.dress-container').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle - I was trying to pull the image and text using the JS and class but it would not work:

http://jsfiddle.net/lmac1/x6kv91qk/

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I was using this [JQuery hide all divs except for the divs I search for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986497/jquery-hide-all-divs-except-for-the-divs-i-search-for)

Comment: Please upload the code to jsfiddle.net

Comment: can you look at it there ryan?

Comment: If you upload the relevant HTML and JS code to http://jsfiddle.net/, we will be able to take a look at your problem and help you find a solution

Comment: no problem Ryan - I will do that I just messaged you via social media as I got your twitter on your profile - if js fiddle is the handiest that is great. When I post it do i just put the link on here for you?

Comment: Hi Ryan - There is some code on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/lmac1/x6kv91qk/  The css is basic for the web page at present - I am going to be using this as a shopping cart using json - just adding a few features for starters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `<div class="dress-container">` is currently wrapping all of your products, therefore you keep on hiding all of them once you use the searchbar.

I fixed your html markup here and removed the `<div class="row">` so they line up nicely when you have filtered them:
http://jsfiddle.net/j7c4kdy3/3/

Comment: Brilliant Ryan works perfectly! Thank you for looking at this, great help, big thumbs up!