# Searching and matching two seperate html-tags values and hide/show matching divs

Tags: jquery, search, input, hide, show

Based on previous discussion here: [dynamically show/hide div based on the input of textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229133/dynamically-show-hide-div-based-on-the-input-of-textbox)

I have a search input, which shows/hides divs below based on the input, matching h4s. If there is an h4 with the value Apple, the .hs_cos_wrapper_widget div with that h4 value will be shown, and the others be hidden.

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var exp = new RegExp('^' + value, 'i');

    $('.product-listing__block--wrapper .hs_cos_wrapper_widget').each(function() {
        var isMatch = exp.test($('h4', this).text()); 
        $(this).toggle(isMatch);
    });
});
```

This works great, as intended. BUT, I am trying to also make it search for tags (Which are located in a div below the h4 with the class .tags)

I am having trouble making it search through both. One try among others was matching content within a wrapping div ".info" with the h4, and tags inside. But with no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved using a different approach discussed here: [Show divs based on text search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510064/show-divs-based-on-text-search) by searching all underlying content instead of in specific tags.

Working example below (Slightly modified from @dku.rajkumar 's code in the linked discussion above)

```
$('#search_download').keyup(function(){
    $('.hs_cos_wrapper_widget').hide();
    var txt = $('#search_download').val();
    $('.hs_cos_wrapper_widget').each(function(){
       if($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(txt.toUpperCase()) != -1){
           $(this).show();
       }
    });
});
```

So the code above filters divs with the class .hs_cos_wrapper_widget below an input field, when the text input is matching any text in those divs.